# Kubernetes: Id or size of image "XXX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/msg/my_image:v1.0" is not set

Tags: docker, deployment, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Today I try to run a cent OS based container as second conatiner in my POD.
While deploying my deployment.yaml I've got this message.

```
ImageInspectError: Failed to inspect image "XXX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/msg/ym_image:v1.0": 
Id or size of image "XXX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/msg/my_image:v1.0" is not set
```

Does somebody know how to set this ID or Size?

Kind regards
Markus

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Failed to inspect image XXX: Id or size of image XXX is not set"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43444711/failed-to-inspect-image-xxx-id-or-size-of-image-xxx-is-not-set)

Comment: Maybe it sound llike that, but the error is not caused by the version of docker or kubernetes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with aws repositories but at first look it seems you are trying to pull image with improper name:tag.

Example of well tagged repository:
**docker tag hello-world aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hello-repository**
Optionally you can add version "*hello-repository:latest*"
You can login to aws account or list your repositories and verify with settings in your deployment.

Could you please verify please if your repository doesn't start at: "msg"
XXX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/**msg**/ym_image:v1.0"

All information about repositories in aws you can find here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Repositories.html
Try to pull mentioned image using Docker and share with your findings.